# How to make the responsive file override the original css file totally in specified breakpoints?

Tags: css

I just found out that specifying a separate css file for responsive design can make some trouble as some rules in the responsive file can not override the original ones sometimes at the specified breakpoints.

I tried some workarounds like using `!important` in stubborn rules and this solved my problem, but i know that using `!important` is known as a very bad practice!

Is there another way that is considered a better practice still keeps my file separate???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resposive css file need to link after style.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
```

Comment: welcome. If the answer is correct, then it is best to accept the answer. Then someone else finds the right answer easily